# Overloading multiple function objects by reference

Tags: c++, overloading, template-meta-programming, c++17, function-object

In C++17, it is trivial to implement an `overload(fs...)` function that, given any number of arguments `fs...` satisfying [`FunctionObject`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/FunctionObject), returns a new *function object* that behaves like an overload of `fs...`. Example:

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct overloader : Ts...
{
    template <typename... TArgs>
    overloader(TArgs&&... xs) : Ts{forward<TArgs>(xs)}...
    {
    }

    using Ts::operator()...;
};

template <typename... Ts>
auto overload(Ts&&... xs)
{
    return overloader<decay_t<Ts>...>{forward<Ts>(xs)...};
}

int main()
{
    auto o = overload([](char){ cout << "CHAR"; }, 
                      [](int) { cout << "INT";  });

    o('a'); // prints "CHAR"
    o(0);   // prints "INT"
}
```

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VvZtKhUEFZ7zyvoa)

---

Since the above `overloader` inherits from `Ts...`, it needs to either copy or move the *function objects* in order to work. **I want something that provides the same overloading behavior, but only references to the passed function objects.**

Let's call that hypothetical function `ref_overload(fs...)`. My attempt was using `std::reference_wrapper` and `std::ref` as follows:

```
template <typename... Ts>
auto ref_overload(Ts&... xs)
{
    return overloader<reference_wrapper<Ts>...>{ref(xs)...};
}
```

Seems simple enough, right?

```
int main()
{
    auto l0 = [](char){ cout << "CHAR"; };
    auto l1 = [](int) { cout << "INT";  };

    auto o = ref_overload(l0, l1);

    o('a'); // BOOM
    o(0);
}
```

```
error: call of '(overloader<...>) (char)' is ambiguous
 o('a'); // BOOM
      ^
```

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/K1a1BqxCV72SbzxZ)

The reason it doesn't work is simple: [`std::reference_wrapper::operator()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/operator()) is a *variadic function template*, which **does not play nicely with overloading**.

In order to use the `using Ts::operator()...` syntax, I need `Ts...` to satisfy `FunctionObject`. If I try to make my own `FunctionObject` wrapper, I encounter the same issue:

```
template <typename TF>
struct function_ref
{
    TF& _f;
    decltype(auto) operator()(/* ??? */);
};
```

Since there's no way of expressing *"compiler, please fill the `???` with the exact same arguments as `TF::operator()`"*, I need to use a *variadic function template*, solving nothing.

I also cannot use something like [`boost::function_traits`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/function_traits.html) because one of the functions passed to `overload(...)` may be a *function template* or an *overloaded function object* itself!

Therefore my question is: **is there a way of implementing a `ref_overload(fs...)` function that, given any number of `fs...` function objects, returns a new function object that behaves like an overload of `fs...`, but refers to `fs...` instead of copying/moving them?**

Comment: The reason why what you did was "trivial" was that you could derive from those types, and therefore use a `using` declaration to bring all of those `operator()`'s into your own overload set. Thus allowing the C++ compiler to do the work of overload resolution for you. Once you can no longer use that trick, you're now stuck with *manually* implementing overload resolution. That will be... decidedly non-trivial. Good luck.

Comment: Basically you need to implement overload resolution in template metaprogramming. Your `overload` can have a single `operator()` template, the you need to select which one of the `Ts...` matches.
You can take inspiration from the implementation of `std::variant` constructor, which basically needs to solve the same problem. `Boost.Variant` implements it [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/boost/variant/detail/initializer.hpp).

Comment: @sbabbi These are very different problems. `variant`'s straightforward, you set up a bunch of `fun(T)` for every type in the variant and run overload resolution with `fun(arg)` to see which one is selected. OP's case is decidedly non-straightforward.

Comment: Back up and solve it for 2 function objects of 1 argument.  We can determine which accept convert-from T and which accept T via `template<class T>struct not_T{operator T()&&;};`  Covering all of the overload rules is probably impossible, however.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Honestly, reimplementing all overload resolution rules sounds like hell, even if I were to use something like `boost::hana`. BTW, here's a possible workaround that abuses *placement `new`* to move back the overloaded functions into their original places: [on wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oV2OVFm3QhbI7aRn)

Comment: Here's a "fake" `ref_overload` implementation: [on wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qc7AxiDtb2PoinHE).

Comment: @Yakk I would go with "definitely impossible". How do you do partial ordering?

Comment: @T.C. I do not know.  But I do know that 2-3 times a year I figure out how to do something I thought was impossible in C++.  So I hedge my bets unless I can prove it impossible, and then I doubt my proof.  Maybe method pointers and manual dispatch; probably not.  I seriously doubt it is possible, but I won't rule it out.

Comment: Perhaps it's possible to bypass the issue by copying `void` pointers to `Ts` instead of copying the `Ts` objects (erasing their type), while still keeping the original types using just the template context, so the `void` pointers can then later be `static_cast` back to `Ts` inside?

Comment: @Danra: I don't see a way that could work - do you have an example? The issue is that I need to inherit from `Ts...` to have `using Ts::operator()...`.

Comment: Perhaps in the future... http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0352r0.pdf

Comment: @metalfox More recent version here http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0352r1.pdf

Comment: I am aware of `operator.` overloading and **really** looking forward to it :) - I need `ref_overload` in C++17, though...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

All right, here's the plan: we're going to determine which function object contains the `operator()` overload that would be chosen if we used a bare-bones overloader based on inheritance and using declarations, as illustrated in the question. We're going to do that (in an unevaluated context) by forcing an ambiguity in the derived-to-base conversion for the implicit object parameter, which happens after overload resolution succeeds. This behaviour is specified in the standard, see N4659 [[namespace.udecl]/16](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udecl#16) and [18](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udecl#18).

Basically, we're going to add each function object in turn as an additional base class subobject. For a call for which overload resolution succeeds, creating a base ambiguity for any of the function objects that don't contain the winning overload won't change anything (the call will still succeed). However, the call will fail for the case where the duplicated base contains the chosen overload. This gives us a SFINAE context to work with. We then forward the call through the corresponding reference.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

template<class... Ts> 
struct ref_overloader
{
   static_assert(sizeof...(Ts) > 1, "what are you overloading?");

   ref_overloader(Ts&... ts) : refs{ts...} { }
   std::tuple<Ts&...> refs;

   template<class... Us> 
   decltype(auto) operator()(Us&&... us)
   {
      constexpr bool checks[] = {over_fails<Ts, pack<Us...>>::value...};
      static_assert(over_succeeds(checks), "overload resolution failure");
      return std::get<choose_obj(checks)>(refs)(std::forward<Us>(us)...);
   }

private:
   template<class...> 
   struct pack { };

   template<int Tag, class U> 
   struct over_base : U { };

   template<int Tag, class... Us> 
   struct over_base<Tag, ref_overloader<Us...>> : Us... 
   { 
       using Us::operator()...; // allow composition
   }; 

   template<class U> 
   using add_base = over_base<1, 
       ref_overloader<
           over_base<2, U>, 
           over_base<1, Ts>...
       >
   >&; // final & makes declval an lvalue

   template<class U, class P, class V = void> 
   struct over_fails : std::true_type { };

   template<class U, class... Us> 
   struct over_fails<U, pack<Us...>,
      std::void_t<decltype(
          std::declval<add_base<U>>()(std::declval<Us>()...)
      )>> : std::false_type 
   { 
   };

   // For a call for which overload resolution would normally succeed, 
   // only one check must indicate failure.
   static constexpr bool over_succeeds(const bool (& checks)[sizeof...(Ts)]) 
   { 
       return !(checks[0] && checks[1]); 
   }

   static constexpr std::size_t choose_obj(const bool (& checks)[sizeof...(Ts)])
   {
      for(std::size_t i = 0; i < sizeof...(Ts); ++i)
         if(checks[i]) return i;
      throw "something's wrong with overload resolution here";
   }
};

template<class... Ts> auto ref_overload(Ts&... ts)
{
   return ref_overloader<Ts...>{ts...};
}


// quick test; Barry's example is a very good one

struct A { template <class T> void operator()(T) { std::cout << "A\n"; } };
struct B { template <class T> void operator()(T*) { std::cout << "B\n"; } };

int main()
{
   A a;
   B b;
   auto c = [](int*) { std::cout << "C\n"; };
   auto d = [](int*) mutable { std::cout << "D\n"; };
   auto e = [](char*) mutable { std::cout << "E\n"; };
   int* p = nullptr;
   auto ro1 = ref_overload(a, b);
   ro1(p); // B
   ref_overload(a, b, c)(p); // B, because the lambda's operator() is const
   ref_overload(a, b, d)(p); // D
   // composition
   ref_overload(ro1, d)(p); // D
   ref_overload(ro1, e)(p); // B
}
```

[live example on wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GGhkr1lbQHvE6KjP)

---

Caveats:

- We're assuming that, even though we don't want an overloader based on inheritance, we could inherit from those function objects if we wanted to. No such derived object is created, but the checks done in unevaluated contexts rely on this being possible. I can't think of any other way to bring those overloads into the same scope so that overload resolution can be applied to them.
- We're assuming that forwarding works correctly for the arguments to the call. Given that we hold references to the target objects, I don't see how this could work without some kind of forwarding, so this seems like a mandatory requirement.
- This currently works on Clang. For GCC, it looks like the derived-to-base conversion we're relying on is not a SFINAE context, so it triggers a hard error; this is incorrect as far as I can tell. MSVC is super helpful and disambiguates the call for us: it looks like it just chooses the base class subobject that happens to come first; there, it works - what's not to like? (MSVC is less relevant to our problem at the moment, since it doesn't support other C++17 features either).
- Composition works through some special precautions - when testing the hypothetical inheritance based overloader, a `ref_overloader` is unwrapped into its constituent function objects, so that their `operator()`s participate in overload resolution instead of the forwarding `operator()`. Any other overloader attempting to compose `ref_overloader`s will obviously fail unless it does something similar.

---

Some useful bits:

- [A nice simplified example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/w0x7yTxdT3eymyRZ) by [Vittorio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/598696/vittorio-romeo) showing the ambiguous base idea in action.
- About the implementation of `add_base`: the partial specialization of `over_base` for `ref_overloader` does the "unwrapping" mentioned above to enable `ref_overloader`s containing other `ref_overloader`s. With that in place, I just reused it to build `add_base`, which is a bit of a hack, I'll admit. `add_base` is really meant to be something like `inheritance_overloader<over_base<2, U>, over_base<1, Ts>...>`, but I didn't want to define another template that would do the same thing.
- About that strange test in `over_succeeds`: the logic is that if overload resolution would fail for the normal case (no ambiguous base added), then it would also fail for all the "instrumented" cases, regardless of what base is added, so the `checks` array would contain only `true` elements. Conversely, if overload resolution would succeed for the normal case, then it would also succeed for all the other cases except one, so `checks` would contain one `true` element with all the others equal to `false`.

  Given this uniformity in the values in `checks`, we can look at just the first two elements: if both are `true`, this indicates overload resolution failure in the normal case; all the other combinations indicate resolution success. This is the lazy solution; in a production implementation, I would probably go for a comprehensive test to verify that `checks` really contains an expected configuration.

---

[Bug report for GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80245), submitted by [Vittorio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/598696/vittorio-romeo).

[Bug report for MSVC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/37376/ambiguous-derived-to-base-conversion-for-the-impli.html).

Comment: This is promising... and scary! I'll have to spend some time studying and understanding this. I edited your answer to add some line breaks, as it was hard to read (especially due to the StackOverflow layout) - hopefully you don't mind.

Comment: Uh, wow. That's brilliant. Wow. I feel like the only thing I provided here is a good test case :)

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Sure, no worries. I think many (most) people will prefer your formatting, so thanks for taking the time to do that. If anyone wants my horizontally squashed version, they can get it from the revision history.

Comment: @Barry Cheers! I do think your answer is very useful in its entirety, and clearly several people agree. Mine breaks two compilers out of three; I'm not sure how I should feel about that :-).

Comment: @bogdan: is there any reason you're using `ref_overloader` in `add_base` and `over_base`? Wouldn't `pack` suffice there?

Comment: @bogdan: a self-contained example that shows how `over_base`,  `add_base`, and `over_fails` work with some hardcoded functions would clarify a lot for me - hopefully that's not too much to ask :)

Comment: After discussing it on cpplang.slack, I reported a minimal example triggering the bug you encountered on gcc: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80245

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Yes, that's the gist of it; good explanation. Thanks for filing the bug against GCC. I'll try to report the one on MSVC tomorrow. The partial specialization of `over_base` for `ref_overloader` does the 'unwrapping' mentioned in the answer to enable `ref_overloader`s containing other `ref_overloader`s. With that in place, I just reused it to build `add_base`, which is a bit of a hack, I'll admit. `add_base` should really be `inheritance_overloader<over_base<2, U>, over_base<1, Ts>...>`, but I didn't want to define another template that would do the same thing.

Comment: Glad to be proven wrong :) Now I'm just waiting for Vittorio to award his bounty so that I can tack on one of my own...

Comment: This is insanely clever, hat tip to you. Only question -- it must be dead simple compared to the rest, but how does `over_succeeds` get away with a single check?

Comment: @Quentin One part reasonable assumption, one part laziness :-). Good question; I've added an explanation to the answer.

Comment: @T.C. "Prove T.C. wrong" - I'm pretty sure there's a paragraph somewhere in the standard making such a statement ill-formed NDR :-). In all fairness, this solution sidesteps the problem that you were discussing with Yakk in the comments, so I think you're being too hard on yourself. Jokes aside, your gesture means a lot to me; thank you.

Answer (score 10):

In the general case, I don't think such a thing is possible even in C++17. Consider the most obnoxious case:

```
struct A {
    template <class T> int operator()(T );
} a;

struct B {
    template <class T> int operator()(T* );
} b;

ref_overload(a, b)(new int);
```

How could you possibly make that work? We could check that both types are callable with `int*`, but both `operator()`s are templates so we can't pick out their signatures. Even if we could, the deduced parameters themselves are identical - both functions take an `int*`. How would you know to call `b`?

In order to get this case correct, what you'd basically need to do is to inject return type into the call operators. If we could create types:

```
struct A' {
    template <class T> index_<0> operator()(T );
};

struct B' {
    template <class T> index_<1> operator()(T* );
};
```

Then we could use `decltype(overload(declval<A'>(), declval<B'>()))::value` to pick which reference to call ourselves.

In the *simplest* case - when both `A` and `B` (and `C` and ...) have one single `operator()` that is not a template, this is doable - since we can actually inspect `&X::operator()` and manipulate those signatures to produce the new ones that we need. This allows us to still use the compiler to do overload resolution for us.

We can also check what type `overload(declval<A>(), declval<B>(), ...)(args...)` yields. If the best match's return type is unique almost all the viable candidates, we can still pick the correct overload in `ref_overload`. This will cover more ground for us, as we can now correctly handle some cases with overloaded or templated call operators, but we will incorrectly reject many calls as ambiguous that aren't.

---

But in order to solve the general problem, with types that have overloaded or templated call operators with the same return type, we need something more. We need some future language features.

Full reflection would allow us to inject a return type as described above. I don't know what that would look like specifically, but I look forward to seeing Yakk's implementation of it.

An alternative potential future solution would be to use overloaded [`operator .`](http://wg21.link/p0416). Section 4.12 includes an example that indicates that the design allows for overloading of different member functions by name through different `operator.()`s. If that proposal passes in some similar form today, then implementing reference-overloading would follow the same pattern as object-overloading today, just substituting different `operator .()`s for today's different `operator ()`s:

```
template <class T>
struct ref_overload_one {
    T& operator.() { return r; }
    T& r;
};

template <class... Ts>
struct ref_overloader : ref_overload_one<Ts>...
{
    ref_overloader(Ts&... ts)
    : ref_overload_one<Ts>{ts}...
    { }

    using ref_overload_one<Ts>::operator....; // intriguing syntax?
};
```

Comment: Good answer. I was hoping for a crazy clever solution but your explanation and examples make me confident that it's currently impossible. A mention + example of a possible `operator.` overloading solution would make this answer even better, and I will very likely award you the bounty *(unless someone miraculously figures something out)*.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Yeah, Stroustrup's `operator.()` says it should support overloading of member names through multiple `operator.()`s. I don't know what the status of that paper is or its relative likelihood of adoption vs some reflection solution. I don't think that Hubert or Faisal's alternative supports this, but I'm not sure.